# How to use primitive types on POST Rest API using eclipselink jpa

Tags: java, api, jpa, exception, eclipselink

I'm trying to create a REST API using Java and JPA (EclipseLink)

The problem is:

I have an ENDPOINT called `sell(long var1, long var2)` which the URI is http://localhost:8080/myproject/api/sell

When i try to call this endpoint sending the bellow payload i got an error:

{
    "var1":"1",
    "var2":"2"
}

```
17-Aug-2019 12:29:51.535 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doDefaultLogging Interceptor for {http://resources.myproject.myname.com/}ProductResource has thrown exception, unwinding now
 org.apache.johnzon.mapper.MapperException: long not instantiable
        at org.apache.johnzon.mapper.MappingParserImpl.buildObject(MappingParserImpl.java:299)
        at org.apache.johnzon.mapper.MappingParserImpl.readObject(MappingParserImpl.java:150)
        at org.apache.johnzon.mapper.MappingParserImpl.readObject(MappingParserImpl.java:142)
        at org.apache.johnzon.mapper.MappingParserImpl.readObject(MappingParserImpl.java:129)
        at org.apache.johnzon.mapper.Mapper.mapObject(Mapper.java:310)
        at org.apache.johnzon.mapper.Mapper.readObject(Mapper.java:228)
        at org.apache.johnzon.jaxrs.JohnzonMessageBodyReader.readFrom(JohnzonMessageBodyReader.java:78)
        at org.apache.johnzon.jaxrs.DelegateProvider.readFrom(DelegateProvider.java:51)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBodyReader(JAXRSUtils.java:1379)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1330)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:856)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:815)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:215)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:78)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.doInvoke(CxfRsHttpListener.java:253)
        at org.apache.tomee.webservices.CXFJAXRSFilter.doFilter(CXFJAXRSFilter.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This problem ONLY happens with not Entities types, like Long, long, Integer, int, String, etc.

If I use `sell(MyLongEntity var1, MyLongEntity var2)` it works fine.

I'm Running this on Java 8, EclipseLink, using Maven and H2 Database (File)

So, do you guys have some ideia on this exception ?

`org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: long not instantiable`

***UPDATE:*** I've changed my POST parameter to use my ENTITY. So, now i call `sell(MyEntity myEntity)` and it Works fine. But I'm still with a lack of knowledge on why i cannot use primitive types on that. As pointed on the comments, it is related to json serialization/deserialization.

Comment: (1) This is clearly a JSON serialization issue, it has nothing to do with eihter `jpa` or `eclipselink`, (2) if `var1` and `var2` are supposed to be longs, why are they strings in the payload?

Comment: Hi @crizzis, I solved the problem by changing the parameters of the POST to be my Entity, then it worked. About serialization/deserialization of JSON I'm still learning about it, thanks for remind me this is basic and important. Also, about the payloads, you were right, i was sending as STRING and it should be LONG (without ""). Tks.